# Keyboard distance in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a simple python algorithm to solve this problem. Can you please help me figure out why my code is not working:

**Problem:**

> Jakub is trying out a one-dimensional keyboard. It consists of a
>   single row of keys. The distance between any two adjacent keys is 1.
>   Each key contains a distinct letter of the English alphabet. Jakub
>   uses only one finger to type on the keyboard. He wonders what is the
>   smallest total distance he will have to move his finger while typing a
>   given word.
>
> For example, if the keyboard's only row is "qwertyuiop", and Jakub
>   wants to type the word "potter", he will have to move his finger from
>   'p' to 'o' (distance 1), from 'o' to 't' (distance 4), from 't' to 't'
>   (distance 0), from 't' to 'e' (distance 2) and from 'e' to 'r'
>   (distance 1), for a total distance of 1 + 4 + 0 + 2 + 1 = 8.
>
> You are given a string keyboard and a string word, describing the
>   keyboard and the word Jakub wants to write. Return the minimum
>   distance he will have to move his finger in order to type the word on
>   the keyboard.

**My Code:**

```
def typingDistance (keyboard, word):
    a=keyboard.find(word[0][:1])
    res=0
    for i in word:
        if keyboard.find(i) != a:
            res+=abs(a-i)
        a = keyboard.find(i)
    return res
```

Comment: I'm not sure this question is appropriate for CS since it's not theoretical; it's a programming problem and should probably be asked on SO instead.

Comment: This site is about computer science. Even if you're following a computer science curriculum, this is not a science question, it's a programming question, so it's off-topic here. For programming questions, ask on [so], not on [cs]. I have migrated this question and your previous question there.

Comment: Do you get an error?  What do you expect?  What does it actually do?

Comment: This is clearly a student trying to do his homework using SO. And this happens A LOT. Should we help these people? I'm thinking not, this very much constitutes cheating. Isn't there a rule somewhere about this kind of thing?

Comment: @letitbee I don't think it's cheating if they are asking for help. It's cheating if they ask for solutions.

Comment: @SamyBencherif S/he is not asking a specific question.  Learning how to troubleshoot is part of learning how to code, and an almighty important one considering  you always have to maintain and debug code.  Personally, unless a student asks a *specific* question or has found that a certain line is a problem, I tend to not help with these questions.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're doing `a-i` where `i` is the letter instead of `a-position`. Factor out the position and voila!

```
def typingDistance (keyboard, word):
    a = keyboard.find(word[0][:1])

    res=0
    for i in word:
        position = keyboard.find(i)
        if position != a:
            res += abs(a-position)
        a = position
    return res
```

---

Note that `word[0]` is a letter and thus `word[0][:1]` is *the same letter* (because `"a"[:1]` is just "a"). So you can leave that out:

Also note that you don't have to do `if position != a` as the distance would be `0` anyway:

```
def typingDistance (keyboard, word):
    a = keyboard.find(word[0])

    res=0
    for i in word:
        position = keyboard.find(i)
        res += abs(a-position)
        a = position
    return res
```

---

Finally note that it might be better to make a mapping at the start that maps letters → their index on the keyboard so you can avoid calling `keyboard.find` too often. This will only help if `word` is much longer than `keyboard`, but it's a good habit to get into when you're learning:

```
def typingDistance(keyboard, word):
    letter2position = {letter: keyboard.index(letter) for letter in keyboard}

    a = letter2position[word[0]]
    res=0
    for i in word:
        position = letter2position[i]
        res += abs(a-position)
        a = position
    return res
```

Note that `letter2position[...]` simply replaces `keyboard.find(...)`; this makes sense if you realise that functions are a mapping of input to output so `letter2position` is sort-of just a function with all of its results pre-calculated..

Comment: Pretty sure the `[:1]` there is a nop

Comment: Thanks, I've mentioned that now.